# How to add "00" in a string and split the values in javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to split the string like this 123,145,678.00 and the input i type in the textbox is 123145678 , also it not allow special character and alphabetic characters .

I try the following

```
var format = function(num){
var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
if(str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
    parts = str.split(".");
    str = parts[0];
}
str = str.split("").reverse();
   for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
       if(str[j] != ",") {
          output.push(str[j]);
              if(i%3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                  output.push(",");
              }
              i++;
          }
      }
      formatted = output.reverse().join("");
      //var value = formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : "");
      //console.log(dotvalue.toFixed(2))
      return("$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : ""));
};
```

Comment: is .tofixed(2) not working?

Comment: i need to add **.00** in the end of the string

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oskansavli/822382 try these

Comment: if you want to add .00 then `.toFixed(2)` should be ok

Answer (score 1):

Try with this..I hope this will help

```
var format = function(num){
var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
if(str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
    parts = str.split(".");
    str = parts[0];
}
str = str.split("").reverse();
   for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
       if(str[j] != ",") {
          output.push(str[j]);
              if(i%3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                  output.push(",");
              }
              i++;
          }
      }
      formatted = output.reverse().join("");
      //var value = formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : "");
      //console.log(dotvalue.toFixed(2))
      return("$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : "")+".00");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add some zeroes at the end, separate the string in parts, concat the last parts with dot and join the rest with comma.

```js
var string = '123145678',
    splitted = (string + '00').match(/^(...)(...)(...)(..)/);

splitted.shift();
splitted[2] += '.' + splitted.pop();
console.log(splitted.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = "35$$##G%%%%^^##dhdfhhdf00";

// converts string to number, strips letters + special characters
var newNumber = Number(number.replace(/[^0-9]+/ig, ""));

// built-in javascript number formatting
var results = newNumber.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

// $3,500.00
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qL0qg8g1/

[Options for toLocaleString here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_locales)

Comment: How I understood your problem is you want a number that has been typed in a text box to be cleaned and turned into a currency value.

If I misinterpreted what you are trying to do, this code should still work as a good starting point for what you're trying to accomplish.